# Yii - Using alternate view file in Yii User module

Tags: module, yii, yii-extensions

Is it possible to use a custom view file in a module (eg. [user](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-user)) in order to keep the module (3rd party) intact? 
Somehow extend the module, with a views folder that holds my custom views.

Answer (score 2):

The path to the module theme views should be

> /{{your_app_name}}/themes/{{theme_name}}/views/user/

Copy all of the module views from the folder

> /{{your_app_name}}/protected/modules/user/views

to the mentioned above folder and that will do the job. After that you could customize the views as you like.

Answer (score 2):

Copy **user** module view files to `<app>/themes/<current_theme>/views/user/`. More general, customize module views using the folowing "formula": `<app>/themes/<current_tehem>/views/<modules_name>/<controller_name>/<view_file_to_customize>.php`

Answer (score 1):

**Use a theme**. For a module named "user" and a view path of "profile/edit", create "/themes/flashy/user/views/profile/edit.php". You can also define a new layout in "/themes/flashy/layouts/column2.php". Then add to your configuration file in "protected/config":

```
return array(
    // many settings...
    'theme' => 'flashy',
```

For the module "user" you pointed out, unfortunately its controllers use absolute paths for their layouts (e.g. "//layouts/columns2") so AFAIK you can't define distinct layouts for the application and this module.

See also the official guide chapter on [theming with Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.theming).

Comment: Thank you, I'm currently using themes for my app, but for some reason the modules wont use the themed files under their respective folders...

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that in many help forums of the Internet, when someone asks abot theming a module, everyone suggests a path alias to the themes folder. I think this is wrong, because it implies modules to be splitted, and modules are supposed to be a black-box that can be used across projects. The advice given in such forums would  only be valid if a theme is shared among several modules. If someone wants to "package" a theme inside a module, she can:
-add an init function to the controller of the module
-inside that init, use the class attribute layout and a path alias, like this, supose a module whose id is "Sample":
then you add, to SampleCOntroller.php:

```
public function init() {
    //BELOW: it will use the layouts/main.php inside the module.
    $this->layouts = "sample.views.layouts.main"; 
}
```